# what is url service from one container to another?

Tags: docker

I have application in c# 'web_dotnet' in one container which downloads data from php service 'web_php' in second container. But what is url for php service? Url 'http://web_php:80' from c# service doesn't work. That is mine docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
   web_php:
     image: php:7.2.2-apache
     container_name: my_php_container
     volumes:
      - ./php/:/var/www/html/
     ports:
       - 3000:80
     networks:
       - mynet

   web_dotnet:
     build: .
     container_name: my_dotnet_container
     ports:
       - 2000:80
     networks:
       - mynet

networks:
   mynet:
     name: xyz_net
     driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can simplify you file, removing unnecessary network declaration and port exposing. `docker-compose` creates default user-defined bridge network for you and links all services to it - no need to do it manually. Also inside network all ports are being exposed to services automatically.

Second, remove `container_name`. You are confusing yourself. Services get their host names equal to service names by default.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
   web_php:
     image: php:7.2.2-apache
     volumes:
      - ./php/:/var/www/html/

   web_dotnet:
     build: .
```

Now, after all useless stuff is cleaned, just call `web_php:80`  from `web_dotnet`.

After, if you would like to access `web_dotnet` ** from outside** `docker-compose`, then you add `ports` directive to make it visible from host.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't connect from dotnet application to php application:
string responseString;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                responseString = client.DownloadString("http://web_php:80");
            }

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is not in docker services - your server replies. You need to play with your URL, not port. Maybe something like `http://web_php:80/`

Comment: I know: service shouldn't have _ in name, so correct name should be: webphp and webdotnet - thx very much - it works :)